# Como implementar um wrapper de ObjectSet que funcione com LinqToEntities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Preciso criar um *wrapper* para `ObjectSet` para poder criar um controle de acesso centralizado.

O objetivo é implementar o CA sem realizar alterações nas queries já existentes no sistema, que no caso, estão espalhadas por todo o código (não existe uma camada centralizada para o acesso aos dados).

A conexão com o banco utiliza um `ObjectContext`.

O *wrapper* de `ObjectSet` criado, é este:

```
public class ObjectSetWrapper<TEntity> : IQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityObject
{
    private IQueryable<TEntity> QueryableModel;
    private ObjectSet<TEntity> ObjectSet;

    public ObjectSetWrapper(ObjectSet<TEntity> objectSetModels)
    {
        this.QueryableModel = objectSetModels;
        this.ObjectSet = objectSetModels;
    }

    public ObjectQuery<TEntity> Include(string path)
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.Include(path);
    }

    public void DeleteObject(TEntity @object)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.DeleteObject(@object);
    }

    public void AddObject(TEntity @object)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.AddObject(@object);
    }

    public IEnumerator<TEntity> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return QueryableModel.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return typeof(TEntity); }
    }

    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression Expression
    {
        get { return this.QueryableModel.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return this.QueryableModel.Provider; }
    }

    public void Attach(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public void Detach(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.Detach(entity);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.QueryableModel.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Ele não é do tipo `ObjectSet`, mas isso não é importante, ele só precisa ser utilizado em queries `LinqToEntities`. E até funciona para consultas simples, como esta por exemplo:

```
//db.Produto é do tipo ObjectSetWrapper<Produto >
var query = (from item in db.Produto where item.Quantidade > 0 select new { item.Id, item.Nome, item.Valor });
var itensList = query.Take(10).ToList();
```

Mas quando existe uma * subquery*, como esta:

```
//db.Produto é do tipo ObjectSetWrapper<Produto>
var query = (from item in db.Produto
             select new
             {
                 Id = item.Id,
                 Nome = item.Nome,
                 QuantidadeVendas = (from venda in db.Venda where venda.IdProduto == item.Id select venda.Id).Count()
             }).OrderByDescending(x => x.QuantidadeVendas);

var productsList = query.Take(10).ToList();
```

Eu recebo um `NotSupportedException`, informando que não é possível criar uma constante do tipo de minha entidade da *subquery* (no caso, `Venda`):

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyNamespace.Model.Venda'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

**Como eu faço para essa query funcionar?** Eu não preciso que o *wrapper* seja do tipo `ObjectSet`, somente que ele possa ser utilizado em queries, mantendo as queries do sistema funcionando.

---

### Updated

Atualize a classe de ObjectSetWrapper para implementar `IObjectSet<TEntity>` como indicado pelo Miguel Angelo, mas os erros continuam. Agora a classe apresenta esta assinatura:

```
public class ObjectSetWrapper<TEntity> : IObjectSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityObject
```

**Para reforçar, a idéia do wrapper é poder realizar verificações de controle de acesso nas queries de consulta, portanto é importante manter as queries com linq to entities já existentes no sistema funcionando.**

Comment: [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) foram projetados exatamente para este tipo de problema, onde nao eh possivel ou desejavel alterar as classes base.  Acredito que esta seria uma melhor solucao para o seu problema ao invez de criar uma _wrapper class_.

Comment: Aparentemente você possui um IQueryable no retorno de vendas, não precisaria mesmo materializar a query em objetos antes. Um chute, tente retirar o `.OrderByDescending(x => x.QuantidadeVendas)` e utilizar somente após materializar a lista, quem sabe seu problema esteja somente aí.

Comment: Acabei de tentar aqui, também não funcionou, continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Sim, me responderam no SO "original", mas tarde eu coloco a resposta aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem tiver o mesmo problema que eu, obtive a resposta que estava procurando no stackoverflow.com pelo Denis Itskovich:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603086/objectset-wrapper-not-working-with-linqtoentities-subquery/21838257#21838257

Comment: Essa solução é muito parecida com a que eu sugeri, com a diferença do QueryProvider.

Answer (score 3):

Possivelmente você terá de implementar a interface `IObjectSet<TEntity>` para que o entity-framework possa saber como trabalhar com esse objeto, caso contrário, o entity vai interpretar esse objeto como sendo qualquer coisa, que não tem nada que ver com ele.

**EDIT**

Vou apontar um caminho que com certeza vai funcionar:

O método `Expression IQueryable.Expression` retorna a expressão que será transformada em SQL pelo Entity. De posse desse objeto, que será obtido do `ObjectSet` original, você deve reconstruí-lo de forma que as referências ao `ObjectSetWrapper` sejam substituidas por referências do `ObjectSet` interno, além de adicionar uma chamada ao método `Where` para filtrar de acordo com o controle de acesso.

Reconstruir a `Expression` é algo que vai dar bastante trabalho, pois é uma AST (árvore sintática abstrata) imutável, ou seja, você vai ter que reconstruir toda a árvore. Para fazer isso, você pode implementar um [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) que irá converter a expressão original:

```
public class ControleAcessoVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        Expression result = node;

        if (node.Value is ObjectSetWrapper)
        {
            result = Expression.Constant((node.Value as ObjectSetWrapper).inner);

            var whereMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(m =>
                m.Name == "Where"
                && m.GetParameters().Length == 2
                && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType
                    .GetGenericArguments()[1]
                    .GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);

            Expression filtroControleAcesso = PegarExpressionFiltroCA();

            result = Expression.Call(whereMethod, result, filtroControleAcesso);
        }

        return base.Visit(result);
    }
}
```

Vou deixar a implementação do método `PegarExpressionFiltroCA` para você, isso vai depender das suas regras específicas.

E no método `Expression IQueryable.Expression` do seu wraper:

```
    Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return new ControleAcessoVisitor().Visit(this.query.Expression); }
    }
```

Espero que valha a pena implementar isso... é uma forma de garantir que o controle de acesso vai funcionar, mas é bem complicadinha.

Comment: Fiz com que meu ObjectSetWrapper implementasse também IObjectSet<TEntity>, mas ainda assim o mesmo erro continua ocorrendo em queries com subquery. Preciso alterar alguma coisa nos métodos já existentes?

Comment: Vou fazer um projeto de teste para reproduzir o problema, e ver se consigo fazer algo.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, não funciona cara. Não faz diferença implementar IObjectSet<T> ou não.

Comment: @AndréPena Eu não tenho como testar agora... isso foi um chute que fazia sentido.

Comment: Eu tenho certeza de uma forma que funciona... mas vai dar um trabalho absurdo pra fazer: reconstruir toda a `Expression`, antes dela ser avaliada pelo entity e colocar o objeto que o entity espera lá dentro da expression tree, e ao mesmo tempo adicionar uma expression `Where` na subquery pra fazer o controle de acesso.

Answer (score 1):

[Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) foram projetados exatamente para este tipo de problema, onde nao eh possivel ou desejavel alterar as classes base.  Acredito que esta seria uma melhor solucao para o seu problema ao invez de criar uma *wrapper class*. Segue um exemplo:

```
public static class ObjectSetExtensions
{
    public static ObjectQuery<TEntity> Include(this IQueryable<TEntity> set, string path) where TEntity : EntityObject
    {
        return set.Include(path);
    }

    public void DeleteObject(this IQueryable<TEntity> set, TEntity @object) where TEntity : EntityObject
    {
        set.DeleteObject(@object);
    }

    // etc

}
```

Assim qualquer objecto do tipo `IQueryable<TEntity>` "ganha" novos metodos. Ex: `meuSet.Include("path")` e `meuSet.DeleteObject(objeto)`.  E as classes originais continuam sendo propriamente reconhecidas pelo EF.

Comment: No meu caso, o principal objetivo é realizar consultas com LinqToEntities sobre o meu wrapper. Acredito que isso não seja possível com Extension Methods, certo?

Comment: Basta continuar usando as classes base para as consultas. Nao ha neste caso a necessidade do _wrapper_ soh para incluir alguns metodos novos.  Os `Extension Methods` lhe dao a fexibilidade de extender a classe sem a necessidade de modifica-la ou criar um _wrapper_.

Comment: A proposito, metodos Linq como `OrderByDescending` sao implementados como `Extension Methods`.

Comment: Ainda assim não vejo como os `Extension Methods` podem me ajudar. Meu cenário é um sistema com mais de 1500 consultas com `LinqToEntities`. Para evitar o refactor de todas estas consultas houve a idéia de criar o wrapper. No momento todas as consultas passam pela minha classe wrapper, então posso ter a implementação do controle de acesso em um único lugar. Como um Extension Method não pode funcionar como um override para um método, não vejo como eles podem me ajudar sem que eu tenha que alterar todas estas consultas já existentes.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho a impressão que sua subquery não está sendo deferida, e portanto, ela tenta ser executada juntamente com a query principal, o que poderia estar causando o erro.

Tente alterar seu código dessa forma:

```
//db.Produto é do tipo ObjectSetWrapper<Produto>
var query = (from item in db.Produto
             select new
             {
                 Id = item.Id,
                 Nome = item.Nome,
                 QuantidadeVendas = db.Venda.Where(m => m.IdProduto == item.Id).ToList().Count() //ToList() para forçar a execução da subquery
             }).OrderByDescending(x => x.QuantidadeVendas);

var productsList = query.Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Mas estou procurando uma solução que não exija alterar as queries já feitas no código. Você conhece alguma outra forma?

Comment: Quando tudo está materializado, tanto db.Produto, quando db.Venda, aí sim tudo funciona.
Mas materializar todos os registros da tabela não é uma opção viável, ainda mais no caso de uma subquery, para cada registro de db.Produto, uma query vai ser realizada no banco.

Ou seja, dessa maneira não gera exception, porém, materializar tudo não é uma opção.

(from item in db.Produto.ToList()
             select new
             {
                 QuantidadeVendas = db.Venda.Where(m => m.IdProduto == item.Id).ToList().Count()
             }).OrderByDescending(x => x.QuantidadeVendas);